# how to remove X-Y values in this fl-chart flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, fl-chart

**I am working on fl-chart (line charts) and I want to remove X-Y labels in this chart as well as grey lines to make a clear look of the chart but I didn't find any customisation in this package. So how can I achieve this task if fl-cart has this option or is there any different package available ?
[image]

#### And also I want to achieve this task so if there is any alternative way please tell me

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I figured it out we can simple add this code in `LineChartData` to remove these titles data:

```
titlesData: FlTitlesData(
              show: false,
            ),// to disable all tiles in graph
```

---

you can also disable required tiles by specifying titles like:

```
 titlesData: FlTitlesData(
                  bottomTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
                  leftTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
                  rightTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
                  topTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false),
)
```

**Update:** *New Way to disbale tiles in new updated lib*

```
titlesData: FlTitlesData(
            leftTitles: AxisTitles(sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false)),
            rightTitles: AxisTitles(sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false)),
            bottomTitles: AxisTitles(sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false)),
            topTitles: AxisTitles(sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false)),
          ),
```

Comment: ***UPDATE***: In the later versions, `topTitles` accept `AxisTitles`, and don't take `SideTitles` directly. So in order to achieve that, the following code should work:
`FlTitlesData(topTitles: AxisTitles(sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false)))`

Answer (score 1):

For fl_chart version 0.55.1+, you have to consider "AxisTitles" before "SideTitle".

thus:

```
            FlTitlesData(
              bottomTitles:
                  AxisTitles(sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false)),
              leftTitles:
                  AxisTitles(sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false)),
              rightTitles:
                  AxisTitles(sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false)),
              topTitles:
                  AxisTitles(sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false)),
            ),
```